# Acessar objeto dentro de objeto (SdtClass - Codeigniter)

Tags: php, codeigniter

Olá!
Através do ajax `data: { 'objeto': JSON.stringify(_obj_devedor) }`; estou enviando o seguinte `objeto` para o servidor.

E no codeigniter, estou convertendo da seguinte forma:
`$objeto = $_POST['objeto'];
 $objeto_decode = json_decode($objeto);`

E acessando os itens (exemplo: contratos) da seguinte forma.
`$objeto_decode->contratos;`

Acontece que só estou conseguindo acessar até este item.
Então como posso acessar itens que estão aninhados aos `contratos`, conforme destacado em vermelho na imagem abaixo, em `negociacoes` e `parcelas`?

Eu já tentei da seguinte forma e não consegui:
`$objeto_decode->contratos->negociacoes;`

### Json

[image: json]

### Objeto

[image: objeto]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basta observar os tipos de cada valor. Isto é, o retorno de:

```
$objeto_decode = json_decode($objeto);
```

Será um objeto, então para acessar o atributo `contratos`, basta fazer `$objeto_decode->contratos`. Porém, o tipo do atributo contratos é `array`, então devemos informar a chave que indica qual é a posição que desejamos. Se for a primeira, basta informar o valor 0 - se forem todas, basta percorrer através de um laço:

```
$objeto_decode->contratos[0] // Retorna o primeiro elemento de contratos
```

Mas cada elemento desse `array` é um objeto que possui o atributo `negociacoes`, então, para acessar esse atributo:

```
$objeto_decode->contratos[0]->negociacoes
```

Novamente, `negociacoes` é um `array` de objetos que possuem o atributo `parcelas`, então devemos informar a chave que indica a posição que desejamos:

```
$objeto_decode->contratos[0]->negociacoes[0]->parcelas
```

Finalmente, `parcelas` também será um `array` de objetos, então, por exemplo, se você precisa do valor da primeira parcela, da primeira negociação, do primeiro contrato, ficaria:

```
echo $objeto_decode->contratos[0]->negociacoes[0]->parcelas[0]->valor;
```

---

Como solicitado nos comentários, para se percorrer todos os contratos, negociações e parcelas, seria necessário um laço de repetição para cada. Veja um exemplo abaixo:

```
// Percorre todos os contratos:
foreach ($objeto_decode->contratos as $contrato) {

    // Percorre todas as negociações:
    foreach ($contrato->negociacoes as $negociacao) {

        // Percorre todas as parcelas:
        foreach ($negociacao->parcelas as $parcela) {

            // Código

        }

    }

}
```

Comment: somente uma dúvida.
Utilizando o foreach, eu posso fazer usar conforme a imagem: https://uploaddeimagens.com.br/images/001/080/685/original/erro.png?1504884435

Comment: Estou recebendo este erro: `Message:  Trying to get property of non-object` no model. Neste linha: `'id' => $ctt->id,`

Comment: Sua função não faz muito sentido, tenta rever o que você fez e entender o problema.